# Error Message as "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime."

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, datetime

My Code:

```
DateTime? birthDate = DateTime.Parse(filterDictionary.ContainsKey("DOB") ? filterDictionary["DOB"] : string.Empty);
```

I am getting Error Message as "String was not recognized as a valid DateTime." How to solve this issue. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem (at least one of them) is that you can't parse an empty string to a `DateTime`.

Change your line of code to this to move the parsing only when you find the key, and return null instead of parsing when you don't have it:

```
DateTime? birthDate = filterDictionary.ContainsKey("DOB") ? DateTime.Parse( filterDictionary["DOB"]) : (DateTime?) null;
```

The other problem might be that your dictionary DOB value is actually not possible to convert to a `DateTime`. If the above code does not work, please edit your question and post the value in `filterDictionary["DOB"]` when you get this error.

Comment: type of conditional expression cannot be determined because there is no implicit conversion between 'System.DateTime' and '<null>' msg is displayed. Thanks.

Comment: @SOUser: See my answer - you need to cast one or other of the operands to `DateTime?`

Comment: Thanks Jon, I have updated my answer now to reflect that change.

Comment: @ØyvindKnobloch-Bråthen, Updated answer working fine as expected. Thank You so much.

Answer (score 1):

Well `DateTime.Parse` is *always* going to fail when you present it with an empty string.

It's not clear whether the time that you've seen this has been one where there *has* been data in the dictionary but it's invalid, or whether there's been no data and it's parsing `string.Empty`. Also note that `DateTime.Parse` returns `DateTime`, not `DateTime?`. If you want the value to be `null` if the entry wasn't in the dictionary, I'd actually use:

```
DateTime? birthDate = null;
string dobText;
if (filterDictionary.TryGetValue("DOB", out dobText))
{
    birthDate = DateTime.Parse(dobText);
}
```

Or perhaps:

```
string dobText;
DateTime? birthDay = filterDictionary.TryGetValue("DOB", out dobText)
    ? DateTime.Parse(dobText) : (DateTime?) null;
```

Note that you need to cast at least one of the second or third operands to `null` here so the compiler can work out the type of the conditional expression.

You should also consider whether a plain call to `DateTime.Parse` is appropriate:

- If you know the specific format you're expecting, call `DateTime.ParseExact`
- If this is *user input*, you should probably be using `TryParse` or `TryParseExact`
- If it's not user input, you should probably be specifying a parsing culture of `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture`
- If it's direct user input in a GUI, is there a way you can avoid getting it as text in the first place?

Comment: TryGetValue is not populated.It is asking whether you missing namespace. I put "system.Data.Common". Also the issue occurs. Thanks

Comment: @SOUser: I'd assumed that `filterDictionary` was a `Dictionary<string, string>` - is it not? (As ever, it's hard to work from partial information.)

Comment: Thanks so much. I took the updated answer from oyvind as you corrected. It is working fine. Thanks.

Comment: @SOUser: Does that mean you've ignored the various other points in my post? Don't just do the first thing that immediately works for the exact data you're using - stop and consider the wider issues.

Comment: Sure. Definitely I will try other alternatives. I will not ignore. Thank You so much.